# TTURLCache to cache my image and data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, three20

I used three20's photo gallery in my app and it worked really well and looked neat and pretty. And basically I don't need to worry about all the fetch-photos-from-the-server thing since three20 has fetched and managed and cached the data for me, all of which are done behind the scene.

That's when I started to notice this magic caching mechanism implemented in three20, called **TTURLCache**. In its header file I find the following interface methods:

```
/**
 * Stores a data on disk.
 */
- (void)storeData:(NSData*)data forURL:(NSString*)URL; //method 1
- (void)storeData:(NSData*)data forKey:(NSString*)key;

/**
 * Stores an image in the memory cache.
 */
- (void)storeImage:(UIImage*)image forURL:(NSString*)URL; //method 2

/**
 * Stores an etag value in the etag cache.
 */
- (void)storeEtag:(NSString*)etag forKey:(NSString*)key; //method 3
```

My questions:

1. Method 1 and method 2 in the above code: are they only capable of storing data, or are they capable of both fetching and storing?
2. What is an etag in method 3?
3. Method 1 says it will store the data on disk, while method 2 says it will store the image in memory. If I use method 2 to store an image, will it get lost once I kill and restart my app?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Those are the storage methods. The retrieval methods are separate. (See below.)
2. Etags are a way to optimize network traffic. [See Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) for a good intro.
3. I *think* that Three20 both stores the image file on disk, and the decoded image itself in memory. Certainly, any in-memory caches would be cleared if the app re-started, but remember that under iOS 4, that probably happens less often that you think.

To get data out of the cache, try one of:

```
/**
 * Gets the data for a URL from the cache if it exists and is newer than a minimum timestamp.
 *
 * @return nil if hthe URL is not cached or if the cache entry is older than the minimum.
 */
- (NSData*)dataForURL:(NSString*)URL expires:(NSTimeInterval)expirationAge
           timestamp:(NSDate**)timestamp;
- (NSData*)dataForKey:(NSString*)key expires:(NSTimeInterval)expirationAge
           timestamp:(NSDate**)timestamp;

/**
 * Gets an image from the in-memory image cache.
 *
 * @return nil if the URL is not cached.
 */
- (id)imageForURL:(NSString*)URL;
- (id)imageForURL:(NSString*)URL fromDisk:(BOOL)fromDisk;
```

I would advise reading through the source, though. If memory serves, TTURLCache isn't all that big a class.

Comment: Thanks Sixten! A few follow-up questions: (1) By saying fetching I mean fetching from the internet, does TTURLCache or three20 provide other methods to fetch from the internet? (2) Regarding images cached on disk and decoded in memory, if I re-start the app and call the **imageForURL:fromDisk:**, will this again put the decoded image in memory? Thanks again.

Comment: The cache doesn't interact with the network directly. See `TTURLRequest` for that (which uses the cache). As to #2, the best recommendation I can give you is to read the source to be sure. (It's generally the best--frequently the only--documentation Three20 has.)